# how to read other language from database?

Tags: android

i have creating one software where when user search for something data from a txt file extracted and appear in display. (something like dictionary.) everything running fine but the app can not read bangla language from the .txt database. instead it displayed space where there are bangla texts.
all i did, make a values-bn folder in res folder. then in values-bn made an strings.xml and given my language value for the activity where bangla text should be shown. like: পরীক্ষা
still it can not read bangla languages from .txt database. how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Make sure your txt file and your strings.xml are **UTF-8** encoded, when you save them

Comment: brother, i have saved both of them in utf-8. by default they r in utf-8. yet not working.

Comment: Well... do you have a font that supports Bangla characters? I find it strange that Roboto doesn't support that... I'm curious, let me do a search. (back from Google) You're right. Look what did I discover... [http://techloverhd.com/2013/08/bangla-font-on-android-4-3-jelly-bean-got-new-look-but-broken/](http://techloverhd.com/2013/08/bangla-font-on-android-4-3-jelly-bean-got-new-look-but-broken/)

Comment: font 'lucida console' is supporting bangla. i am using it in .txt file.

Comment: And... it seems I also found a solution: [http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2232235](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2232235)

Comment: So, now your Bengali users will be happy! Hooray!!

Comment: ha ha! thanx a lot bro. let me try it out... u really discoved gold mine...